# How can I ignore TypeScript decorators (use NestJS entities like usual types)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator, nestjs

I wanted to know if there is a way to ignore the TypeScript decorators and reuse the same file without them. In NestJS I'm defining an entity like this.

```
import { PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, Entity } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ length: 100 })
  name: string;

  @Column({ length: 320 })
  email: string;
}
```

But everywhere except for database `typeorm` configuration I need exactly the same type just without the decorators.

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
}
```

Redefining types makes the code vulnerable to errors and disregards the *don't repeat yourself* principle. This might be self explanatory but I do not see it yet. Can I use the first one like usual (e.g. `let user: User;`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use your entity as a type, you could even add other annoations, e.g. `class-validator` assertions to it. As long as `typeorm` (resp. `class-validator`) is not involved, the decorators will just be ignored.

Note though that reusing your database schema throughout your whole application creates dependencies and makes it harder to change your database schema (for example for performance optimization). Especially in larger applications, it makes sense to separate the API schema (easy to consume, closer to real world entities) and the database schema (more technical, e.g. relations, technical details) with an adapter layer. It's basically a trade-off between DRY and encapsulation, see this [thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/303480/316673) for an extended discussion.